# Update a listboxitem through code where a specific column = value x

Tags: c#, listbox, refresh, listboxitem

I have a wpf form with a listbox that has 2 columns.

I use this code to add values to the listbox :

```
playersOnlineList.Items.Add(new { Username = username, Status = "Lobby" });
```

I use this code to remove values from the listbox:

```
playersOnlineList.Items.Remove(new { Username = username, Status = "Lobby" });
```

My question is how do update the value of "Status" where username = x?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using an anonymous type. The items returned by the `Items` collection of the listbox are returned as `object`. In order to access properties of the items you would need to cast them, which you cannot do since the type is anonymous. Create an explicit class for your items.

```
class UserStatus
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        UserStatus other = obj as UserStatus;
        return other != null && other.Username == Username && other.Status == Status;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked {
            int hash = 17;
            hash = hash * 31 + Username == null ? 0 : Username.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 31 + Status == null ? 0 : Status.GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can search for the index of the item

```
for (int i = 0; i < playersOnlineList.Items.Count; i++) {
    var userStatus = (UserStatus)playersOnlineList.Items[i];
    if (userStatus.Username == x) {
        userStatus.Status = newStatus;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I need to link the listbox to the custom class?

Comment: Yes. How do you want to cast an object otherwise: `((type??)obj).Username`. If you do this `var x = new { Username = username, Status = "Lobby" }; string s = x.Username;` then `x` is implicitly typed as your anonymous type and therefore you can access its fields, but this does **not** work `object obj = new { Username = username, Status = "Lobby" }; string s = obj.Username;`

Answer (score 0):

You would probably have to do something along the lines of this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < playersOnlineList.Items.Count; i++) {
        if (playersOnlineList.Items[i].Username == x) {
            Player p = playersOnlineList.Items[i];
            p.Status = newStatus;
            playersOnlineList.Items[i] = p;
        }
    }
```

Unless I am misinterpreting your question, this should solve your problem. Re-assigning should work well in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Second line will not work because you are creating a new object, not passing existing one which you want to remove. You should make a class that will have Username and Status properties, and than populate the `ListBox` using `ItemsSource`:

```
            User user = new User(); //your custom class
            user.Username = username;
            user.Status = "Lobby";
            List<User> source = new List<User>();
            source.Add(user);
            //add more users here

            listBox.ItemsSource = source;
            //removing a user
            source.Remove(user);//if you have the instance
            //if not, find user by username and remove it
            User userToRemove = null;
            foreach (User user in source) {
                if (user.Username == "myUserName") { 
                    userToRemove = user;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(userToRemove != null)
                source.Remove(userToRemove);
```

To edit the user, just change the properties if you have the instance, if not, find it based on username and change it.

Comment: Anonymous types override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`. Therefore the second line will work.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I didn't know that. Thanks for the tip. I still think it's a bad approach, considering that he wants to change some objects.

Comment: Yes, binding a `BindingList<T>` to the listbox would be a preferred approach. It would allow you to work with a typed list instead of having to deal with the innards of a listbox.